# How to print extra object in an array of objects after comparison?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, Q_type: "AL"},
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 4, Q_type: "DL"}
]
const array2 = [
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 4, Q_type: "DL"}
]

const arrAfterComparison = array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val))
```

I am trying to compare `array1` and `array2` and getting the object which is **not** present in both of these arrays

**Expected output**

```
arrAfterComparison = [{id:1,Q_type:"AL"}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Andreas added my unsuccefful attempt.. i have tried many solutions but i am stuck here :(

Comment: @Phil expected o/p would be this `[{id:4,Q_type:"AL"}]` or `[{id:1,Q_type:"AL"}]` ?

Comment: my bad .. it will be `[{id:1,Q_type:"AL"}]`

Comment: @Phil u sure it's just one object there that is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.some()` inside `Array.filter()` method callback.

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, Q_type: "AL"},
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 4, Q_type: "DL"}
]
const array2 = [
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 1, Q_type: "DL"}
]

const output = array1.filter(item => !array2.some(a => a.Q_type === item.Q_type))
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This solves it flawlessly.. been stuck here for a while .. never had to use the `some()` method before i will read the docx thanks

Comment: Don't you think there will be another question anywhere on SO that already solves this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you compare, actually 2 objects are not similar.. look closely(it isn't an error)

1. Both the ones with `id:1` have different values for `Q_type`
2. The one with the id of 4(we all see this one)

```js
const array1 = [
  {id: 1, Q_type: "AL"},
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 4, Q_type: "DL"}
]
const array2 = [
  {id: 2, Q_type: "BL"},
  {id: 3, Q_type: "CL"},
  {id: 1, Q_type: "DL"}
]

function oddIndexesOut(_arr1,_arr2){
  //objects may "look" the same but if they don't point to the same thing, they're not equal.. however if i turn it into a string, things that "look" equal are equal
  _arr1=_arr1.map(a=>JSON.stringify(a))
  _arr2=_arr2.map(a=>JSON.stringify(a))
  
  //comparison function(if things "look" similar)
  function compare(arr1,arr2){
    var x=arr1.filter(a=>!arr2.includes(a))
    return x.map(a=>JSON.parse(a))
  }
  
  //the longest array is used(so that checking can be full)
  if(_arr1.length>_arr2.length){
    return compare(_arr1,_arr2)
  }
  return compare(_arr2,_arr1)
}

console.log(oddIndexesOut(array1,array2))
```